# How To Changing Printer Scaling on Mac OS X 10.8.2

Tags: macos, printing

I am currently having an annoying problem where anything I print in Mac OS X 10.8.2 is scaled to 3%, and I cannot seem to change this through the printing menu.

I've attached a picture of my printing presets which shows that the scaling is stuck at 3%, though I cannot reset the scaling from this menu. The presets window shows the "scaling" option under "Copies & Pages" but this does not show up in the printing drop-down menu... so I'm stuck.

Does anyone know how to change this setting?

[image: Printing Presets]
[image: Printing Menu]

Comment: What printer is it? those are the printer settings not OS x.

Comment: The settings are the same no matter which printer I choose. I actually do not even want to print. I only save the document as a PDF, but I can't since everything is scaled to 3%.

Comment: The second picture is the default Print Menu that pops up in MS Word / TextWrangler... so I'm assuming that it's the same for all OS X apps. I can change it in Preview, but that's about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I did.

In for example TextEdit...

I used the Page set up!

In there you can adjust the scaling

Now go to the print and check you settings in show presets, current.

[image]

Comment: This looks promising! Where is the "page setup" in TextEdit?

Comment: Found it! Page Setup is under the File Menu. This is honestly something that just has to be fixed in OS X.

Answer (score -2):

Your first step is to try printing to .pdf from a [virgin] User Account.

Failing that test, I would reinstall the O.S.